# Using np.average in groupby or any aggregate function with parameters

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am now running into a problem of calculating group weighted average in pandas.

Suppose the dataframe has 3 columns 'Group','A' and 'W'. If I want to find group mean of A, I will just do

```
df.groupby(['Group'])['A'].mean()
```

Or if I need overall weighted average I can do

```
np.average(df.A,weight=df.W)
```

But can I calculate weighted average for each group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You could use groupby/apply with a custom (lambda) function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2015)
N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N,3)), columns=['Group', 'A', 'W'])
result =  df.groupby(['Group']).apply(lambda x: np.average(x['A'], weights=x['W']))
print(result)
```

yields

```
Group
0    4.422978
1    4.557099
2    4.517336
3    4.535559
4    4.526898
5    4.697104
6    4.580512
7    4.598492
8    4.388965
9    4.424191
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  If I would like to use the resample function of pandas (essentially groupby slice), could I do that as well ?

Comment: That depends. To call `df.resample` requires `df` to have a DatetimeIndex, PeriodIndex or TimedeltaIndex.

Comment: Is there a way to do that with using `.agg()` so it works with multiple columns as well?